# Best way to export html to Word without having MS Word installed?

Tags: html, ms-word

Is there a way to export a simple HTML page to Word (.doc format, not .docx) without having Microsoft Word installed?

Comment: Try some online tool like [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have only simple HTML pages as you said, it can be opened with Word.

Otherwise, there are some libraries which can do this, but I don't have experience with them.

My last idea is that if you are using ASP.NET, try to add `application/msword` to the header and you can save it as a Word document (it won't be a real Word doc, only an HTML renamed to `doc` to be able to open).

Comment: This method refers to emailing the html, but applies to ms word too:  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122006-1.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool called JODConverter which hooks into open office to expose it's file format converters, there's versions available as a webapp (sits in tomcat) which you post to and a command line tool. I've been firing html at it and converting to .doc and pdf succesfully it's in a fairly big project, haven't gone live yet but I think I'm going to be using it.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jodconverter/

Comment: I didn't end up using it, it turned out that it leaked memory too badly for production use.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source project called [HTMLtoWord](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmltoword/) that that allows users to insert fragments of well-formed HTML (XHTML) into a Word document as formatted text.

[HTMLtoWord documentation](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/WW40/Using+HTMLToWord#UsingHTMLToWord-whatis)

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to make a ".doc" Microsoft Word file, it would probably be easier and more portable to make a ".rtf" file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in Java, you can convert HTML to real docx content with code I released in [docx4j 2.8.0](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/docx4j-2-8-0-released/).  I say "real", because the alternative is to create an HTML **altChunk**, which relies on Word to do the actual conversion (when the document is first opened).

See the various [samples prefixed ConvertInXHTML](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples). The import process expects well formed XML, so you might have to tidy it first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many third party tools for this. I don't know if it gets any simpler than that.

Examples:

- http://htmltortf.com/
- http://www.brothersoft.com/windows-html-to-word-2008-56150.html
- http://www.eprintdriver.com/to_word/HTML_to_Word_Doc.html

Also found a [vbscribt](http://www.interclasse.com/scripts/html2word.php), but I'm guessing that requires that you have word installed.

Answer (score 1):

I presume from the "C#" tag you wish to achieve this programmatically.

Try [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately Aspose.Words has an ImportHTML process, but it doesn't support CSS.  So you will have to manually recreate all formatting in the resulting doc.  This includes table formatting, lists, and text styles.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just HTML, all you need to do is change the extension to .doc and word will open it as if it's a word document.  However, if there are images to include or javascript to run it can get a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

i believe [open office](http://www.openoffice.org/) can both open .html files and create .doc files

Answer (score 0):

use this link to export to word, but here image wont work:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html