# How to convert Tinymce HTML code generated in the front end to a word file[.doc]?

Tags: .net, tinymce, openxml

I'm working on doing a online word processor, such as Google Docs, Zoho etc..
I want to create its front end using Tinymce editor, i.e front end of the editor will be done using Tinymce. But i want to convert this front end generated by tinymce into a word file[.doc] at the server end.. so, tell me how to convert this HTML representation exactly to its word file.. Server end using ASP.net and C#.net.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you save the tinymce content on serverside to a file and then use [one of the methods described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151/best-way-to-export-html-to-word-without-having-ms-word-installed) to create a file openable by Word.