# How to convert Html code to Word Document in C#

Tags: c#, .net

i had a situation where i will get html code. Form that i need to generate a word document using C#.Net .
Can any one help ......

We can consider any html code

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:18pt;"><u><b>Joy wood</b></u></span> </p>
            <p style="text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> &nbsp;</p>
            <tk_metadata name="last_modified" value="21/05/2019, 22:33"> </tk_metadata>
            <tk_metadata name="author" value="Preeti chawla"> </tk_metadata>
            <p> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-indent:-0.25in;text-align:center;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:12pt;"><b>Full stack Java Developer</b></span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-indent:-0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:12pt;"><b> <br> <br></b></span></p>
            <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:14pt;"><b>Professional Summary</b></span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Proficient in Java design patterns including Singleton, Dependency Injection, Factory, Model View Controller (MVC), Data Access Object (DAO). Well versed in core java concepts like Collections, Multi-threading, Serialization.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Expertise in object modelling and Object Oriented design methodologies (UML). Experience with UML diagrams like Class, Object, Use Case, State, and Activity diagrams.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Expert knowledge over J2EE Design Patterns like MVC Architecture, Front Controller, Session Facade, Business Delegate and Data Access Object for building J2EE Applications.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Worked with JAVA 8 features like Stream API, Time API, Functional Interfaces Multithreading, Transaction Management, Exception Handling, and Collection API.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Strong experience with frontend technologies like HTML5, CSS3, Scripting languages like JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX, Angular JS, Angular 2, ReactJS, NodeJS and good knowledge in Bootstrap, SASS.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Experienced with AngularJS directives ng-app, ng-init, ng-model for initialization of AngularJS application data, implemented AngularJS Expressions, Directives, Controllers, filters and created Angular JS service layer.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Expertise in spring framework, including Spring IoC/core, Spring MVC, Spring DAO support, Spring ORM, Spring micro services, Spring AOP, Spring Security, Spring MVC, Spring Cache, and Spring Integration, and Spring Boot, Spring REST.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Experienced in implementing Micro services using Spring Boot using technologies Restful, JAX-WS, JAX-RPC, Axis, Soap, XML, WSDL, SAX and SAAS based design.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.11in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Experience in web services technologies like REST, SOAP, WSDL, JMS and Service Oriented Architecture (SOA).</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Reviewing the Database Schemas across the different domain. Worked on the Integration of the Code and deliver the build to UAT Team.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Used extensively Eclipse in development and debugging the application.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Developed JUnit test classes for Controller, Service and Data layers.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-indent:-0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> &nbsp;</p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:center;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:12pt;"><b><i>Erie Insurance Group. Erie, PA. Oct 2012 – April 2014</i></b></span></p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:center;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:12pt;"><b>Java Developer</b></span></p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-indent:-0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;"><b>Responsibility </b></span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Client engagement developer and implementation engineer for code install to production.<br> <br> • Developed front-end using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Performed client-side validations using JavaScript and jQuery Framework.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Developed the view components using JSP, HTML, Struts Logic tags and Struts tag libraries.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Responsible for understanding the functional requirements, writing the technical design and developing the requirements.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Application server upgrades testing support.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Developed and maintained web applications utilizing open source technologies like Hibernate ORM, Spring Frameworks.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;"> Designed applications mainly using Spring MVC module.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Managed Object Persistence, Data retrieval using JPA, JDBC and hibernate with DB2 as backend.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Used JNDI to lookup for the data sources required.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Added functionality that ingested data from a SOAP web service.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Reviewed and signed off QA test plan and Test case documents.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Used JUnit for Unit testing and Involved in performing Integration testing of the whole application.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Implemented log4j for application logging and to troubleshoot issues in debug mode.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">CVS was used as version control system.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-indent:-0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> &nbsp;</p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:center;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:12pt;"><b><i>Barnes &amp; Noble. Dubuque, IA. Aug 2011 – Sept 2012</i></b></span></p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:center;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:12pt;"><b>Java Developer</b></span></p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-indent:-0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;"><b>Responsibility </b></span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;"> Developed GUI using JSP, Struts frame work.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Developed Action forms, Action classes using Struts framework to handle user requests.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Implemented Struts Bean Tags, Logical Tags and Display Tags in JSPs.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Coded Entity Beans for data persistence within Data Layer.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Developed user interface components for Deal, Activity modules along with business components.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Designed and deployed server side EJB (Session Beans and Entity Beans) components on Eclipse IDE.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Written SQL, PL/SQL and stored procedures as part of database interaction.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Responsible for code merging modules using clear case.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Responsible for change requests and maintenance during development of the project.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Developed project in Eclipse IDE.</span> </p>
            <p style="margin-left:0.25in;text-align:left;margin-top:0.00in;margin-bottom:0.00in;"> <span style="font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11pt;">Worked with JBoss EAP Command Line Interfaces.</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because no demonstrable effort has been made by the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831900/11425141

as well as 
[What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)
to specify the mime type

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151/best-way-to-export-html-to-word-without-having-ms-word-installed